# django nonrel appengine problem with syncdb

Tags: google-app-engine, django-nonrel, attributeerror

I'm new to django, and still figuring out a lot of things.

When I run the syncdb command of manage.py, after some of the steps have been completed, I get this:

AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'mkstemp'" in > ignored

how do I solve this? Is there a version of django nonrel that solves this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"gagan" posted the reason and solution [right here](https://groups.google.com/group/django-non-relational/browse_thread/thread/b4d1bab0e030c976?pli=1).

> I changed my settings.py little bit to resolve this.  I added following to settings.py,

```
DATABASES['native'] = { 
        'ENGINE': 'djangoappengine.db', 
        'HIGH_REPLICATION': True, 
        'DEV_APPSERVER_OPTIONS': { 
            'high_replication' : True, 
            'use_sqlite': True, 
            } 
    }
```

> and removed this line,

```
DATABASES['native'] = DATABASES['default']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be the [allbuttonspressed](http://allbuttonspressed.com) version. I tried it in march and the exmples from waldemar worked (but I chose plain gae for my project).